# Await a task in anonymous object selected with Linq select

Tags: linq

When I try to run this code, it throws this error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.)

> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

```
var returnFacilitators = facilitators.Select(async f => new
{
    Name = f.DisplayNameLastFirstDegreeTitles(),
    Value = f.FacilitatorId,
    FirstName = f.FirstName,
    LastName = f.LastName,
    DegreeTitles = f.DegreeTitles,
    CanDelete = await facilitatorService.CanRemoveFacilitatorAsync(f.FacilitatorId)
}).ToList();
```

CanRemoveFacilitator is an async Task<bool>.

Comment: Can you show us how you're injecting your context in the `Startup.cs` file?

Comment: Something strange here, I hope you do not cal `WaitAll` at the end? If yes, it will not work, because DbContext is not thread safe and tasks awaited in such manner will cause DbContext reentrance.